# Bigquery Transfert tool bug - "Invalid machine type dts-eu in zone europe-west1-b: googleapi"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm currently transferring my data from Redshift to BigQuery. The transfers where working fine until a few days ago, but suddenly for a few days now, I'm having this error message every time I try to launch a transfer:

```
Error code 3 : { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid machine type dts-eu in zone europe-west1-b: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/bqdts-eu/zones/europe-west1-b/machineTypes/dts-eu' was not found, notFound.", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid machine type dts-eu in zone europe-west1-b: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/bqdts-eu/zones/europe-west1-b/machineTypes/dts-eu' was not found, notFound.", "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest", "debugInfo": "detail: \"[ORIGINAL ERROR] cloud-kubernetes::3: Invalid machine type dts-eu in zone europe-west1-b: googleapi: Error 404: The resource \\'projects/bqdts-eu/zones/europe-west1-b/machineTypes/dts-eu\\' was not found, notFound. [google.rpc.error_details_ext] { code: 3 message: \\\"Invalid machine type dts-eu in zone europe-west1-b: googleapi: Error 404: The resource \\\\\\'projects/bqdts-eu/zones/europe-west1-b/machineTypes/dts-eu\\\\\\' was not found, notFound.\\\" }\"\n" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }
```

Even when I just relaunch transfers that were working before, I've got this same bug. I haven't been able to get support from Google itself, so if someone here knows how to fix this, that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need Google Support for this. When you say that you cannot get support, what do you actually mean? Open a support ticket. Google will respond within the response time for the support plan that you have (4 Hr / 1 Hr). Google Cloud does not have free technical support except for billing questions.

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks for that. Yes, I think we'll have to go through the paying support. I was asking here first because it wasn't clear, as a Google Customer Success Engineer told us that we could have a free technical support for this. But it seems that we can't.

Comment: Create a bug here on BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers. Remember to include your failed job id.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you describe was a known issue which has been resolved. 
A fix has been pushed to production on the 20 October. 
The issue should have been fixed by now.